# How do I record users logged in and not logged in on a website using Perl?

Tags: perl, logging

How do you keep statistics of users logged into a website, and users not logged into a website all in the Perl language?

Answer (score 2):

You write a database, decide how long the maximum amount of time they can access the website without re-authenticating, and then query the database for everyone that matches that criteria.

Web pages aren't that easy to just pick a number and go with it.  Logging doesn't help.  You need a user database for your system, and within it you need to track the last access times and count the people that haven't timed out.  Otherwise, web based logins basically never end as there is no end-criteria to their browser that you have access too (even with session cookies, they can leave their browser running for years).

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the database. I completely agree with you. I completely forgot about that. But apparently for this project I can only use java, linux, and perl to complete this task. How would I do that without using a database?

Comment: @user1938536 You don't.

Comment: Write to a file.  A "flat file" can be a database too.  A very inefficient one, but one none the less.